# How can I contact get my Facebook account back?

Tags: facebook, account-recovery, facebook-account

My friend has been using her Facebook account very frequently via her Facebook app. Because the app was never signed out so she forgot her password and worse, she didn't even have any email addresses attached to her account. However, she does has access to her phone number which she told me that she used that phone number during the signup process.

How can she recover her account using her phone number? I tried to help her to recover her password but kept getting the same thing as in the attached photo.

[image: this is what i get]

Comment: Where does clicking on the button take you?

Comment: To get to this step, I clicked on `Forgot my password` in Login page and it prompt me to enter my name or email or phone number, i tried all of them except email because the account doesn't have one then it led to this. If I click on `I cannot access my email account`, it told me that it can't confirm my identity and guide me to a stupid help page. If I click on `Try again`, it displays the same as the image.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/100530880039294):

> **I signed up with my mobile number and now I can’t log in.**
>
> If you can't [log in](https://www.facebook.com/login) with your mobile number:
>
> - Make sure you enter your entire phone number, including the country code
> - Leave out any extra zeros, + signs or other special characters
>
> If you still can't log in or forgot your password, [request a new one](https://www.facebook.com/login/identify).
>
> Note: If you signed up for Facebook from your mobile phone, you can use your phone number and the password you created during the signup process to [log in](https://www.facebook.com/login) from a computer. or phone.

Try above steps from a system.

Have a look at this page for more information: https://www.facebook.com/help/132243923516844

Or report a login issue:
https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/357439354283890

Comment: The thing is she didn't remember her password, not her number. I tried those steps but no differences. Btw, your last link doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to put entire phone number, including country code without zeros or +sign? Did you try to request new password from the given link? Did you fill the form (last link of answer)?

Comment: I did, I couldn't even get into the new password form because of that page as the image. Your last link doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to find your account? First check it from here: https://www.facebook.com/login/identify, enter, your phone number or name or username, if you don't know username, ask any of your friend what is showing your username. Check the edited part of the answer and report your login issue to Facebook.